# Image tracking code using opencv in python

Tags: python, performance, beginner, opencv

I wrote this code to track small moving objects falling down a chute. The code works buts runs too slowly: using 60 FPS 1920 by 1080 footage the code only runs at about 10 FPS. The problem there is somewhat self-explanatory as I need the program to be able to process footage accurately at real-time speeds and need a very high FPS as the parts move extremely rapidly. Is there anything I can do to improve the run time? I initially tried using a simple neural network but training it proved to be excessively time consuming while this yielded an accurate result in much shorter time.

I'm a mechanical engineer and had to learn this in about a week, so sorry for any obvious mistakes.

Video footage can be seen here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zs5YekjqhxA&feature=youtu.be

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time

start_time = time.time()
count=0
ID=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
TrackList=[]

def nothing(x):
    pass

def isolate(img, vertices):
    mask=np.zeros_like(img)
    channelcount=img.shape[2]
    match=(255, )*channelcount
    cv2.fillPoly(mask, vertices, match)
    masked=cv2.bitwise_and(img, mask)
    return masked

#read video input
cap=cv2.VideoCapture('testGood.mp4')

#background removal initiation either KNN or MOG2, KNN yeilded best results in testing
back=cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorKNN()

#grab initial frames
_,frameCap1=cap.read()
check , frameCap2=cap.read()

#main loop
while cap.isOpened:
    #ensure there are frames to read
    if check == False:
        break

    #image preprocessing
    #declare region of interest eliminating some background issues
    tlX,tlY,blX,blY,brX,brY,trX,trY=400,0,400,800,1480,800,1480,0
    region=[(tlX,tlY),  (blX, blY),(brX,brY) , (trX, trY) ]

    grab=isolate(frameCap1,np.array([region],np.int32))
    frame=cv2.pyrDown(grab)

    #isolate region of interest
    roi1=isolate(frameCap1,np.array([region],np.int32))
    roi2=isolate(frameCap2,np.array([region],np.int32))

    #drop resolution of working frames
    frame1=cv2.pyrDown(roi1)
    frame2=cv2.pyrDown(roi2)

    #apply background subraction
    fgmask1=back.apply(frame1)
    fgmask2=back.apply(frame2)

    #remove shadow pixels and replace them with black pixels or white pixels(0 or 255)
    fgmask1[fgmask1==127]=0
    fgmask2[fgmask2==127]=0

    #apply a threshhold, not necessary but cleans ups some grey noise
    _,thresh1=cv2.threshold(fgmask1,200,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    _,thresh2=cv2.threshold(fgmask2,200,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

    #find movement
    diff=cv2.absdiff(thresh1,thresh2)
    contours, _=cv2.findContours(diff,cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)   
    movement=False
    moveBox=[]
    for contour in contours:
        if cv2.contourArea(contour)<1350 or cv2.contourArea(contour)>3500:
            continue
        #cv2.rectangle(frame,(x,y), (x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)
        (x,y,w,h)=cv2.boundingRect(contour)
        moveBox.append([x,y,w,h])
        movement=True
        continue
        #cv2.putText(frame, 'Status: ()'.format('Movement'),(x,y),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,1,(0,0,255),3)

    #update existing IDs
    for tracked in TrackList:
        success, box=tracked[2].update(frame)
        if success:
            x,y,w,h=[int(v) for v in box]
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (x,y), (x+w, y+h),(0,0,255),2)
            cv2.rectangle(thresh1, (x,y), (x+w, y+h),(255,255,255),2)
            tracked[3].append([x,y,w,h])
        else:
            tracked[3].append(None)

    #check for tracking which has stopped or tracking which hasnt moved
    delList=[]
    p=0
    for tracked in TrackList:
        if len(tracked[3])==1:
            continue
        moved=True
        n=len(tracked[3])-1
        if  tracked[3][n]==tracked[3][n-1] and tracked[3][0]!=tracked[3][n]:
            if tracked[3][n][1]>tracked[3][0][1]:
                count+=1
                print('count1: ',count)
                ID.append(tracked[0])
                cv2.putText(frame, 'Counted',(tracked[3][-2][0],tracked[3][-2][1]),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,1,(0,200,255),3)
                delList.append(p)
            else:
                ID.append(tracked[0])
                delList.append(p)
                print('discard 1')
                cv2.putText(frame, 'discard 1',(tracked[3][-2][0],tracked[3][-2][1]),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,1,(0,200,255),3)
                print(tracked)
        elif n>5 and tracked[3][n]==tracked[3][n-1] and tracked[3][0]==tracked[3][n]:
            ID.append(tracked[0])
            delList.append(p)
            cv2.putText(frame, 'discard 1',(tracked[3][-2][0],tracked[3][-2][1]),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,1,(0,200,255),3)
            print('discard 2')
        elif tracked[3][-1]==None:
            count+=1
            print('count2: ',count)
            ID.append(tracked[0])
            cv2.putText(frame, 'Counted',(tracked[3][-2][0],tracked[3][-2][1]),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,1,(0,200,255),3)
            delList.append(p)
        p+=1

    cv2.putText(frame, 'Count: '+str(count),(50,50),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,1,(0,200,255),3)

    if len(delList)>0:
        for a in delList:
            TrackList[a]=None

    #remove dead IDs
    cleaned=False
    while cleaned==False:
        try:
            TrackList.remove(None)
        except ValueError:
            cleaned=True

    #check if movement was being tracked
    untracked=[]
    if movement==True:
        checkContours,_=cv2.findContours(thresh1,cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
        for contour in checkContours:
            tracked=False
            if 3500>cv2.contourArea(contour)>1350:
                (x,y,w,h)=cv2.boundingRect(contour)
                for box in TrackList:
                    if box[3][-1][0]<x+w/2<box[3][-1][0]+box[3][-1][2] and box[3][-1][1]<y+h/2<box[3][-1][1]+box[3][-1][3]:
                        tracked=True
                if tracked==False:
                    #print('false')
                    (x,y,w,h)=cv2.boundingRect(contour)
                    cv2.rectangle(frame, (x,y), (x+w, y+h),(255,0,0),2)
                    cv2.rectangle(frame, (x,y), (x+w, y+h),(255,255,255),2)
                    untracked.append([x,y,w,h])

    #assign tracking
    ID.sort()
    for unt in untracked:
        idtemp=ID.pop(0)
        tempFrame=frame
        temp=[idtemp, 0, cv2.TrackerCSRT_create(),[unt]]
        temp[2].init(tempFrame,(unt[0],unt[1],1.10*unt[2],1.10*unt[3]))
        TrackList.append(temp)

    #show frames
    cv2.imshow('frame 1',frame)
    #cv2.imshow('frame 2',thresh1)

    #read new frame
    frameCap1=frameCap2
    check, frameCap2=cap.read()

    #wait delay for a key to be pressed before continuing while loop or exiting
    key=cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if key==27:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
print(count)
print("runtime: %s seconds" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I changed your [title to actually state what your code is supposed to do](/help/how-to-ask) and also added the [tag:beginner] tag, since you said you don't have a lot of experience (this is not meant to offend you, merely as a hint towards reviewers).

Comment: Maybe you should also upload the original video file somewhere, because YouTube runs your video through yet another codec, which usually decreases the video quality (especially if fast moving things are involved).

Comment: I can't see this as a code review, so it's a comment. An obvious place to start improving the performance of the code is reducing the preprocessing. The input is   124,416,000 three byte pixels second. It's all getting uncompressed from mp4. Then 80% of the IO and decompression is discarded when downsized to 1080x400 before thresholding discards more work. For a machine learning pipeline, all that data massaging can be done offline. For a real-time system it has a direct impact on performance. A monochrome lower resolution camera designed for computer vision, might be the way to go.

Comment: @benrudgers It's a good point. You should be able to reconfigure the camera to simply capture in a lower resolution (and probably even in greyscale), which will not require post-processing.

Comment: @Reinderien Since the code mentions .mp4, a camera that does not compress the video stream might also be appropriate. It might be possible to reconfigure a consumer oriented camera, but selecting the right camera for the job probably makes more sense if labor costs are ordinary. 0.5 megapixels at 60 fps in monochrome with a c-mount lens of the right focal length is likely less than $1k. Code that never runs is faster than anything a person can write.

Comment: Do you need your video to be in such a high quality? If you reduce the image quality, you could process the video much faster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I'll say that it's very impressive for you to have gotten this working and with mostly reasonable methods, given one weeks' experience.

### Range usage

```
ID=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

can be

```
ID = list(range(10))
```

### No-op function

Based on what you've shown us, `nothing` does, well... nothing. It can be deleted.

### Formatting

There's a code formatting standard called PEP8 that attempts to make Python code more legible, mostly by defining spacing. Software such as PyCharm or the various linters will suggest that

- You should have spaces around `=` in assignments such as `mask=np.zeros_like(img)`
- Variable names like `channelcount` should be `channel_count`
- There should be a space after `#` in comment lines
- etc.

### Tuple unpacking

```
_,frameCap1=cap.read()
```

This is fine. If you don't want to unpack, and you don't want to use the `_`, you could also

```
frameCap1 = cap.read()[1]
```

The same applies to your `threshold` calls.

### Boolean comparison

```
if check == False:
```

should be

```
if not check:
```

Similarly,

```
while cleaned==False:
```

should be

```
while not cleaned:
```

This:

```
if movement==True:
```

should be

```
if movement:
```

### No-op continue

This loop:

```
for contour in contours:
    if cv2.contourArea(contour)<1350 or cv2.contourArea(contour)>3500:
        continue
    #cv2.rectangle(frame,(x,y), (x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)
    (x,y,w,h)=cv2.boundingRect(contour)
    moveBox.append([x,y,w,h])
    movement=True
    continue
```

does not need a `continue` at the end; you can delete that.

### Except-or-break

This loop:

```
#remove dead IDs
cleaned=False
while cleaned==False:
    try:
        TrackList.remove(None)
    except ValueError:
        cleaned=True
```

shouldn't use a termination flag. Instead:

```
while True:
   try:
      TrackList.remove(None)
   except ValueError:
      break
```

### Magic numbers

They abound in this program. Rather than writing literals like `3500`, you should assign them to named constants for legibility's sake, e.g.

```
MAX_CONTOUR = 3500
```